# How to escape special characters?

Tags: shell, command-line, sed

I'm trying to remove songs via a bash shell for loop yet removing a file like this

```
while read item; do rm "$item"; done < duplicates
```

keeps getting caught up on song name.  Is it possible to get around this?  My song titles might look like this:

```
/home/user/Music/Master List's Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Music/John\ Mayer/Room\ for\ Squares\ \[Aware\]/07\ 83.m4a
/home/user/Music/Master List's Music/bsg\ season\ 1\ \(Case\ Conflict\ 1\)/06\ A\ Good\ Lighter.mp3
/home/user/Music/Master List's Music/Nino\ Rota/The\ Godfather\ Pt.\ 3/14\ A\ Casa\ Amiche.m4a
```

as you can see, in order to remove an item I can have no %.()[] or anything else without being escaped unless it's the . before the file extension obviously.  Is there a way I can escape special characters like this?

For instance, I used sed to turn the %20 into spaces:

```
cat duplicates | sed 's/%20/\\ /g' > clean_duplicates
```

The output I'm looking for looks like this:

```
/home/user/Music/Master\ List\'s\ Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/John\ Mayer/Room\ for\ Squares\ \[Aware\]/07\ 83.m4a
/home/user/Music/Master\ List\'s\ Music/bsg\ season\ 1\ \(Case\ Conflict\ 1\)/06\ A\ Good\ Lighter.mp3
/home/user/Music/Master\ List\'s\ Music/Nino\ Rota/The Godfather\ Pt\.\ 3\/14\ A\ Casa\ Amiche.m4a
```

Comment: Can you be sure that two files `foo%20bar` and `foo bar` are really duplicates? I.e. exactly the same file so that you can confidently blow away `foo%20bar` without losing anything?

Comment: Or are you saying that the duplicates file contains percent-encoded names, but the files in the filesystem do not have such names?

Comment: @Kaz, a solid question...I am using banshee's banshee.db file which has already indexed everything and those file names I've listed are actually the URI in a table with all the tracks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** To address the actual url-decoding (I missed it before):

```
while read line; do printf "$(echo -n $line | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/\(%\)\([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]\)/\\x\2/g')\n"; done < input
```

Output:

```
/home/user/Music/Master List's Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/John Mayer/Room for Squares [Aware]/07 83.m4a
/home/user/Music/Master List's Music/bsg season 1 (Case Conflict 1)/06 A Good Lighter.mp3
/home/user/Music/Master List's Music/Nino Rota/The Godfather Pt. 3/14 A Casa Amiche.m4a
```

So in order to delete those files, e.g. redirect the cleaned output to a file:

```
while read line
do 
    printf "$(echo -n $line | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/\(%\)\([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]\)/\\x\2/g')\n"
done < duplicates > cleaned_duplicates

while read file; do rm -v "$file"; done < cleaned_duplicates
```

If you prefer to store the names into a script files using *explicit* shell character escaping you could do

```
while read file; do printf "rm -v %q\n" "$file"; done < cleaned_duplicates > script.sh
```

Which should result in `script.sh` containing:

```
rm -v /home/user/Music/Master\ List\'s\ Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Music/John\ Mayer/R
rm -v /home/user/Music/Master\ List\'s\ Music/bsg\ season\ 1\ \(Case\ Conflict\ 
rm -v /home/user/Music/Master\ List\'s\ Music/Nino\ Rota/The\ Godfather\ Pt.\ 3/
```

Comment: I ran your in two ways, 1. what you wrote above and it seemed to echo lots of lines before it crashes my terminal and 2. just running your sed command and it seemed that the only difference was %20 was replaced by \x20 and so on.

Comment: To rule out copy/paste error I copied the line as I actually have it in my history: it works for me :)

Comment: Yes!  I'm not sure how it works but it does indeed get rid of the url-decoding bit.  @sehe, do you by chance know how to escape/put a backslash in front of the characters like '()[]./ and the whitespace character by chance?  Telling bash to delete a file with any of the characters in the name of the directory or filename will blow up and not work.

Comment: @BrandonMinton Ironically that bit was in [the first version of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9940978/1). However, I think you don't need it if you do it properly. I have updated the answer. Oh, and [don't forget to upvote helpful answers, and accept the answer that answers your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)